# How do I add jQuery to a Blazor server app?

Tags: jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm attempting to add some jQuery to a Blazor server app. Specifically being able to autocomplete an InputText field on a form (where id = 'CompanyName') which is on a razor page (`CreateNote.razor`). When I run the app, autocomplete doesn't work. I've added the alert line to test if that executes and that works fine.

_Layout.cshtml:

```
...
</head>
    <link href="TelephoneNotes.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eTyxS0rkjpLEo16uXTS0uVCS4815lc40K2iVpWDvdSY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://tofsjonas.github.io/sortable/sortable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://tofsjonas.github.io/sortable/sortable.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
            $("#companyName").autocomplete({
                source: ["Apple", "Google", "Facebook"],
                minLength: 3
            })

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
    });

        })</script>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
```

CreateNote.razor:

```
<EditForm Model="@newNote" OnSubmit="@InsertNote">
...
    <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
        <label for="company" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Company:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="companyName" class="form-control" placeholder=""
                       @bind-Value="newNote.CompanyName" />
        </div>
    </div>
...
</EditForm>
```

UPDATE:

I've created an `init.js` with the `wwwroot` folder:

```
function CompleteFormControls() {
    $("#companyName").autocomplete({
        source: ["Apple", "Google", "Facebook"],
        minLength: 3
    }
```

I've added the following line to the bottom of _Layout.cshtml before the closing body tag:

```
<script src="/init.js"></script>
```

I've create a `JSInterop` class:

```
namespace TelephoneNotes.Services
{
    using Microsoft.JSInterop;

    public class JSInterop
    {
        private readonly IJSRuntime js;

        public JSInterop(IJSRuntime js)
        {
            this.js = js;
        }

        public async ValueTask InvokeCompleteFormControls()
        {
            await js.InvokeVoidAsync("CompleteFormControls");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

CreateNote.razor:

```
@page "/createnote"

<PageTitle>Create Note</PageTitle>

@using TelephoneNotes.Data
@inject NotesService NotesService
@implements IDisposable
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<h1>Create Note</h1>

<EditForm Model="@newNote" OnSubmit="@InsertNote">
    <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top: 5px;">
        <label for="company" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Company:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <InputText id="companyName" class="form-control" placeholder=""
                       @bind-Value="newNote.CompanyName" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top: 15px;">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private List<string?> companyNames = new List<string?>();
    private TelephoneNotes.Services.JSInterop? jsClass;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        jsClass = new(JS);
        companyNames = await NotesService.GetCompanyNames();
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await jsClass.InvokeCompleteFormControls();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() => jsClass?.Dispose();
}
```

However when I run the app and go to the create note page, I receive the following error:

```
Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'CompleteFormControls' ('CompleteFormControls' was undefined).
```

Any suggestions why?

_Host.cshtml:

```
@page "/"
@namespace TelephoneNotes.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
<script src="/init.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see that you adjusted your question, but you still has to add you `script` to `_Host.cshtml` and not `_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: @user13256346 I've added what my _Host.cshtml looks like to the OP. I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't see `<body>` tag!, it is a normal html page

Comment: @user13256346 That's the default scaffolded code that was generated when creating the solution. Even if I wrap the scrip tags within body tags, I get the same issue.

Comment: I edited the solution with using `setTimeout` and delay, I tested also and it works perfect!

Comment: @user13256346 I've seen your edit suggestion. Do I need to add all the html tags within the _Host.csthml and if so, why?

Comment: Yes I think that you need because it is normal html page!, at least with my current version of Blazor that I have, anyway if you can not see it in your version and it has been deleted, that means it is hidden and you still can add it as normal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245761/discussion-between-user13256346-and-bhav).

Comment: DO you has an update?!

Comment: @Nb777 I've added an update to the OP. Its adding text at the bottom of the page for some reason?

Comment: What do you mean? can you explain more?

Comment: @Nb777 I'll post a new question as I think its specifically a jQuery issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use Js like this in `Blazor`.

**What is `$( document ).ready() {}`?**
It means that the code inside this scope `{}` will render just and only once the page DOM is ready for JS code to execute.

**When is the DOM ready in Blazor?** 
In most cases you have to execute the JS code in the bult-in `OnAfterRender` function because in this point you will be sure that DOM is complete and you can use JS to manipulate the front-end.

**What is the best way to execute JS functions?**

1. Create a separate file(`MyJs.js`) for Js in the `wwwroot` folder and add your JS functions there.

   ```
   function CompleteFormControls ()
   {
     setTimeout(() => {
       if($("#companyName") != null){
         $("#companyName").autocomplete({
         source: ["Apple", "Google", "Facebook"],
         minLength: 3});
       }
    },500);
   }
   ```
2. Add your Js file 'MyJs.js' in the end of the body of your _Host.html and it should be down of `jquery`:

   ```
   <body>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/MyJs.js"></script>
   </body>
   ```
3. Create a class file to represent your functions in `MyJs.js` file:

   ```
   puplic statis class JsHelper
   {
    [DebuggerHidden]// tell VS Don't debug this function
    puplic statis aasync ValueTask CompleteFormControlsAsync(this IJSRunTime)
    {
     await js.InvokeVoidAsync("CompleteFormControls");
    }
   }
   ```
4. Inject `IJSRuntime` in your razor page:

   ```
   [Inject] private IJSRuntime Js {get; set;}
   protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
   {
     if(firstRender)
     {
       await Js.CompleteFormControlsAsync();
     }
   }
   ```

Note: You can also replace `OnAfterRenderAsync` and use some event like `Click` event, because in this case you are sure that the DOM has also completed rendering.

Comment: I receive a "Could not find 'CompleteFormControls' ('CompleteFormControls' was undefined)." error

Comment: @Bhav, Sorry,  you need to add your js file in `_Host.html`, please check the solution again

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript at the end of the body tag. The current location you've put it $("#companyName") will be null. The component has to be loaded before your javascript executes.

```
<html>
<body>

<Your Components will be here>

 <script type="text/javascript">$(function () {
            $("#companyName").autocomplete({
                source: ["Apple", "Google", "Facebook"],
                minLength: 3
            })

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
    });

        })</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: So I've moved the javascript code to the bottom of _Layout.cshtml just before the closing body tag however that's not made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor does not understand the query selector `'$'`, you need to replace it with keyword `document`.

Answer (score 0):

In `Pages/_Layout.cshtml` add the following snippet to the end of the body along with your JS script:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
```

***In this case your JS script will be in wwwroot/js folder***

In the CreateNote.razor:

```
IJSRuntime _js

//other code here

@code {
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
  {
      await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("CompleteFormControls");
  }
}
```